# Как скрыть некоторые параметры при GET передаче данных с формы?

Tags: html, html-form

Имеем форму:

```
<form id="messageForm" action="search" metod="get">
<input id="id" name="id" type="text">
<input id="city" name="city" type="text">
<button type="submit" id="send">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

при передаче формируется адресная строка по примеру index.php?city=Ростов-на-Дону&id=10

Возможно передавать только id, а city не показывать в адресной строке?

Comment: Можете "закодировать", либо использовать [POST](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/boost/frontend/get-vs-post), либо вместо прямого названия использовать ID

Comment: да вот я и не знаю как убрать city=Ростов-на-Дону (полная строка index.php?city=Ростов-на-Дону&id=10). Надо как то при отправке из формы ее отключить

Comment: Храните объект на сервере , по типу `"ID": "NAME"`, обращаетесь к серверу `?city=61`, а на сервере уже ищите по объекту. Это вариант, где вы используете ID города, а не его название. P.s. Удобно будет использовать такой формат, если сайт будет мультиязычным.